# Video recorded with built-in recorder plays upside down in Android

Tags: android, video

I use the following code to start the built-in recorder and record a video with the *front camera in portrait mode*:

```
 Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
 {
    startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
 }
```

When I open the video from gallery, it is played ***upside down***.

I tested it by starting the camera recorder from the menu and recorded a video with the front camera in portrait mode. On playback, it is also flawed and played upside down.

Is it a phone bug? It is tested with Samsung and Sony and both play upside down.
Could anyone verify that every phone has this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in short: **no, vendors don't even try to rotate the recorded video** (most likely it is not possible in Android systems).

It was **verified** by **SONY**, with their phone *Xperia J*. Their official answer excludes using *portrait* mode with the front camera:

```
Dear Mr. ....., 
Thank you for contacting Sony Xperia Support. 
With regards to your inquiry we would like to inform you that you can use the front camera to record video in the following way.
1. From the Home screen tap the Application screen icon.
2. Find and tap Camera.
3. If the video camera is not selected, drag the icon next to the on-screen button to the left side.
4. Select the Front video mode.
5. Hold the phone in landscape orientation.
6. Tap to start recording.
7. At the end of your video tap to stop recording.
In that way you will not see your videos upside down.
In case you have further issue or question, do not hesitate to contact us. We are always at your disposal. For more information on our products, services and support please visit www.sonymobile.com. 
Please be aware that if you do not respond within 7 days of this email your query will be automatically closed. Any further communications will not reach our support and a new query will need to be raised.

Kind Regards,
xxxxxxxxx
Sony Xperia Support
```